# Capture files pending loading via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, cross-browser

[image]

I'm trying to capture the list of files that are pending loading, with more than 5 seconds of waiting, but I can only see this data after the file is loaded.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the list of files pending to be loading?